# Statistics based on empirical distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\beta:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ and $\alpha > 0$ and $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ a random sample from a distribution with continuous c.d.f $F$ and $\hat{F}_n$ the empirical distribution function. We define statistics: $V_{\beta, \alpha} = \int \beta(\hat{F}_n(x))|\hat{F}_n(x)-F(x)|^{\alpha}\hat{F}_n(dx)$. How to show that the distribution of $V_{\beta, \alpha}$ does not depend on $F$?

Comment: Do you mean, how to show that the distribution of $V_{\beta,\alpha}$ does not depend on $F$?

Comment: Yes, but I am not even sure how to start.

Comment: Do you know why the Kolmogorov Smirnov test statistic has the same property?  The formula for it is simpler, and once you see the principle it is easy to transfer to your case.